# How to add custom input type button in forms?

Tags: forms

I want to add custom input type button in form.
I tried following code, but it is converting it to submit type button.
How can i add  input type button ?

```
$form[custom_button] = array('#type' => 'button','#value' => t('Test Button'),);
```

Comment: Hi, I think it's not possible this way. Please read this on SE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585017/in-drupal-7-form-api-how-do-i-create-an-input-of-type-button-not-submit

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

It's not converting it to a submit button type, they are different

Form items of type "button" will trigger the form submission but won't trigger the hook_form_submits like a form item of type "submit" does. It's eseentially a blank button apart from hook_validate is called but in there you can do whatever special functionality your button is supposed to do